# On repeat executions, SSIS package does not run, but does not error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I've been running into a problem on occasion for a few weeks where I will execute an SSIS package, and it won't run. The stripes don't appear on the background, the spinning yellow/green/red circles don't come up, the progress bar does not appear, and none of the data that is supposed to be transferred is transferred. However, I have to hit the stop button in order to do anything else, as if the package is running. I realized when trying to troubleshoot a specific package today that it often happens when the same package is run more than once. It will run successfully once, but on the second try, it usually just hangs. I've tried closing and reopening the package, closing and reopening visual studio, and have tried using both VS2010 and 2012, but found that restarting my computer is the only thing that seems to make the package run properly. But I can't restart my entire computer every time I need to run a package more than once! One of my coworkers has run into this problem randomly also. Has anyone else seen it or have any idea what it could be?

Comment: I used to face the same issue, but just a stop and restart worked for me. Did you try running the package from a [SQL Server Agent job](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139805(v=sql.90).aspx). Usually, everytime you run the SQL Server job, it will run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

IS this behavior only with this package or you are facing issue with any package? Disable most of the Tasks and start with one by one and see where exactly is the issue.